# What is 1000 ethereum coins?

Tags: ether

I was given 1000 ethereum coins. I don't understand ethereum. I know there are 1 million coins in one bitcoin.  Are ethereum coins divided like that? Just trying to understand what 1000 ethereum really means. Please explain so a newbie can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. IMO [reddit](http://reddit.com) looks like more open to discussion like this than here. In SE we are expecting more tech related questions.

Comment: Thank you.  I was told the 1000 had a value of about $200 about 3 weeks ago

Comment: If you put your public address in [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) you'll be able to see exactly how much you actually have and how much it is worth.

Comment: How many finney do.i.need to.equal i et
hereum

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21250)

Answer (score 1):

It must be 1000 Milliether which is equivalent to 1 ether, not 1000 ethereum,

Here is how both bitcoin and ethereum are divided into small units.

**Bitcoin (BTC)**

The smallest unit in a Bitcoin is Satoshi(named after its creator Satoshi Nakamoto).

These are the breakdown of the one BTC.

```
1 satoshi = 0.00000001  BTC  
10 satoshi = 0.00000010  BTC
100 satoshi = 0.00000100  BTC    micro-bitcoin (μBTC) 
1,000 satoshi = 0.00001000  BTC
10,000 satoshi = 0.00010000  BTC
100,000 satoshi = 0.00100000  BTC    milli-bitcoin(mBTC)
1,000,000 satoshi = 0.01000000  BTC    centi-bitcoin(cBTC)
10,000,000 satoshi = 0.10000000  BTC     deci-bitcoin(dBTC)
100,000,000 satoshi = 1.00000000  BTC      bitcoin(1BTC)
```

**Ethereum (Ether, ETH)**

Ethereum is dividable in to Wei, Kwei/Ada/Femtoether, Mwei/Picoether/Babbage, Gwei/nano/Nanoether, Szabo/Microether/Micro, Finney/Milliether/Milli, Kether/Grand/Einstein, Mether, Gether and Tether.

```
1000000000000000000 Wei =  1 Ether

1000000000000000 Kwei =  1 Ether

1000000000000 Mwei =  1 Ether

1000000000 Gwei =  1 Ether

1000000 Szabo =  1 Ether

1000 Finney =  1 Ether

1 Ether =  1 Ether

0.001 Kether =  1 Ether

0.000001 Mether =  1 Ether

0.000000001 Gether =  1 Ether

0.000000000001 Tether =  1 Ether
```

hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Ethereum has a metric system of denominations used as units of ether.
>   Each denomination has its own unique name (some bear the family name
>   of seminal figures playing a role in evolution of computer science and
>   cryptoeconomics). The smallest denomination aka base unit of ether is
>   called **Wei**. Below is a list of the named denominations and their
>   value in Wei. Following a common (although somewhat ambiguous)
>   pattern, ether also designates a unit (of 1e18 or one quintillion Wei)
>   of the currency. *Note that the currency is not called Ethereum as
>   many mistakenly think, nor is Ethereum a unit.* [Ethdocs](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ether.html#denominations)

[image: table]

*I cannot say for sure, but in your case it could possibly be a [tokens](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/ethereum-token/).*

> what 1000 ethereum really means

There is no such unit as ethereum, it is called `ether`.

Comment: Ethereum has no "metric system". It has a **decimal** system.

Comment: @Distic this is a quote from [Ethdocs](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ether.html#denominations).

Comment: Aren't they the same things? :-)